# How to properly use the TypeDefinition and Object instances in OPC UA with the OPC foundation UA-.net standard libraries

Tags: c#, plc, opc, opc-ua

Reading through some of the OPC UA documentation that is out there 
([OPC UA eBook](https://www.academia.edu/35573027/OPC_UA_eBook)), ([github repo](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard)), ([Home page](http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-.NETStandard/))
you come across Type definitions and how they can be used to blueprint any object that references it.

However, going through some of the example code in the github repo, I can't find a clear example how a type definition makes data access easier or cleaner.

For instance:
In solution 'UA QuickStart applications' in the github repo there is windows forms project 'Boiler client' that uses 2 different 'Boiler Type' instances in the address space and projects its variables onto textboxes depending of the selected combobox item.
When looking at the code you can see that the boilers are indeed selected using the 'Boiler Type' flag but the properties that are to be mapped are still hardcoded and found using relative paths instead of using the Type.

[Two different boiler instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGmqU.png)

[Fetch boilers method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzDkN.png)

[Boiler client with seperate variable display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j2VC.png)

Currently, consuming OPC UA data( nodes) for me means I have to make a list of each and every one of all the node addresses I want to read and using them in the Session.Read() or listening on them with a MonitoredItem.
Instead, I think it should be possible to read all the nodes in an object and map them to CLR object.

My Question: 
Is it possible with the C# repo to capture data from whole objects (using the type definition or otherwise) instead of having to read every single node manually using its address? (read("node address"))

Alternative question: 
What's the use of even adding a type definition if it can't be leveraged in a consumer? 
Is it a comfort for PLC programmers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is already contained in your question. Yes, you use relative paths to reach the nodes of the actual Object. But the relative paths are dictated by the Type, and they the same for all Objects of that Type. So, the Type gives you (among other things) the knowledge of the relative paths. And you can rely on the fact that the same relative path can be used with any such Object. That is the "leverage in a consumer" you are asking for.

But no, there is no generic "give me all" read service for an Object. You still need to read each piece individually. This makes sense because the full contents of the Object might be huge (if not even infinite), so for efficiency the client application need to pick what it actually needs. Again, this answer is implicitly contained in your question, because you wrote "I have to make a list of each and every one of all the node addresses I want to read" - but somebody else will need different ones.

Some servers may provide the most important information about the object in a single Variable, perhaps as custom DataType, but you cannot rely on it in general case.